# Updating an options label using Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a select created in Dojo and a form that can 'rename' the selected option, however I am having issues changing the label of the option that is listed under the select.

I have tried several things:

```
var selectDropdown = registry.byId("stateSelect");
selectDropdown.updateOption({
    value : currentId, // the existing ID to update
    label : this.new_name
});
selectDropdown.reset();
```

does not change the label.

```
selectDropdown.set("displayedValue", this.new_name);
selectDropdown.reset();
```

also does not work even though

```
selectDropdown.get("displayedValue");
```

prints out the old label that I am trying to change.

**edit:**
here's how I create the Select and add items to it...

```
var select = new Select({
    name : "stateSelect",
    }, "stateSelect");

select.addOption({
    value : 0,
    label : "test"});
```

Comment: What is the widget type behinds `selectDropdown` ?

Comment: Did you try `selectDropdown.get('selectedOptions').label = 'foo'` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That changes the item that is selected, but only after I re-select it. It also does not change the old label in the dropdown box (only the selected label on top).

Comment: I edited the question to include how I was creating the Select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it with a combination of `.get('selectedOptions')` and `.updateOption()` :

```js
require(['dijit/form/Select'], function(Select) {
  var select = new Select({
    name : "stateSelect"
  }, "stateSelect");
  
  select.addOption({
    value : 0,
    label : "test 0"
  });
  select.addOption({
    value : 1,
    label : "test 1"
  });
  select.addOption({
    value : 2,
    label : "test 2"
  });
  
  
  changeBtn.onclick = function() {
    select.get('selectedOptions').label = (new Date()).toString();
    select.updateOption(select.get('selectedOptions'))
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<div class="tundra">
  <div id="stateSelect"></div>
  <button id="changeBtn">change selected to current date</button>
</div>
```

Comment: There was actually an error in my code and I was using the wrong index with updateOption. updateOption alone seems to be sufficient. Thank you, though!